# GTK window as desktop background, how to lower the stacking order

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk3

Not sure if a phrased the title correctly. But basically i'm trying to write a little c program in gtk3, running on xubuntu and xfce, to set a gif as the desktop background. I'm able to keep the window below all other windows using gtk_window_set_keep_below(). However desktop launcher/icons are still below it. Also i want the window to behave like wallpaper, so when i right click on it, you get the normal desktop right click menu. Are these things even possible using gtk? I had a look through the api but found nothing. Any ideas?

So far i have everything except for the two behaviours i described.
Here is the code i use to create the window.

```
static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *layout;
  GtkWidget *image;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  layout = gtk_layout_new(NULL, NULL);
  image = gtk_image_new_from_file("/some/path/pic.gif");

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), layout);
  gtk_widget_show(layout);
  gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(layout), image, 0, 0);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 500, 340);

  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(window, TRUE);
  gtk_window_set_type_hint((GtkWindow*)window, (GdkWindowTypeHint)GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DESKTOP);
  gtk_window_set_decorated((GtkWindow*)window, 0);
  gtk_window_set_keep_below((GtkWindow*)window, 1);
  gtk_window_set_accept_focus((GtkWindow*)window, 0);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}
```

Comment: Any reason you added a tag for an unrelated language?

Comment: Not really. Fixed.

Comment: You did not understand my comment. To be clear: Don't spam tags! C and C++ are different languages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just create a new window and hope it will magically replace the desktop. You say that you already have a desktop with launchers, so you can't just add something, you have to replace that. The example I know, nautilus (aka GNOME Files) handles the desktop. It's a file manager, and the desktop is just a special maximized view of a directory.

Xfce must do it the same way. So the launchers and the desktop background are in the same application, in the same widget tree. I don't think you can put something in between. So either you change your wallpaper using your existing file manager, or you implement your own view that totally replaces it (but then you most probably will lose the launchers features unless you re-implement them, which might take ages if you're inexperienced).

If you really want to heavily customize that desktop view, in last resort, you may just fork the program that handles it and add your customizations there.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Makes sense now, seems like more trouble then its worth.